# Remove GET query in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a `.htaccess` file that converts the URL in a path query. It does work but when I go to something like this: `localhost/login` I get this `localhost/login?path=login`. How can I change it so that I don't see the path in the URL?

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^__init__\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __init__.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: No, this is the only one

Comment: When i change my controller to use test instead of login then the path query is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `login.php` exist as a physical file? If so, then you will need to make sure `MultiViews` is disabled. Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> There is a folder called login

Ah, that will be the problem. mod_dir with issue an external redirect from `/login` to `/login/` (ie. append a trailing slash). Since a redirect has already been issued, your internal rewrite now becomes an external redirect (since the HTTP status and `Location` headers have already been set).

You need to either change the name of that directory. Or disable this feature of mod_dir (but this can result in further problems). For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: no it doesn't exist in real life i call a function to make the page

Comment: There is a folder called login but when i add this in my .htaccess i still get the path query